# reactjs and mongoose fetch documents issue

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, next.js

I have implemented the infinite scroll without using any NPM packages. It's working fine. However my back-end mongoDB fetch same data multiple times. How can I fixed it?

**Note**: some search found skip. limit isn't good enough for large set of data instead of use **range**. How can I used it?

**Nextjs service**

```
export const getMobilePosts = async (skip: any) => {
  endpoint = config.post.getMobilePosts + `?skip=${skip}`;
  return Axios.get(endpoint);
}
```

**Loop through the data received from the back-end**

```
  try {
      const { data } = await getMobilePosts(skip);
      const filterData = await data?.filter(obj => obj.adPromote == "free-ad" || obj.adPromote == "reach-up-ad")
          .sort((f,p)=>{
              if (f.adPromote === 'reach-up-ad' && p.adPromote !== 'reach-up-ad') {
                  return -1;
                } else if (f.adPromote !== 'reach-up-ad' && f.adPromote === 'reach-up-ad') {
                  return 1;
                }
              return 0;
          })
          .map(obj => {
              return {
                  ...obj,
                  title: `${obj.title} (${obj.features.condition})`
              }
          });
      setPost([...post, ...filterData]);
      setSkip(filterData.length);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
```

**Back-end Node and express service code**

```
export async function getMobilePosts(skips: any) {
        try{
            const skip = skips ? Number(skips) : 0;
            const PER_REQUEST = 5;
        
            return await Post.find({expiredAt: {$gte: currentDate},status: 'live'},
                                    "document fields goes here")
                                    .sort({_id: -1 })
                                    .skip(skip)
                                    .limit(PER_REQUEST)
    
        } catch(error: any) {
            throw new Error(error as any);
        }
  }
```

Inspected the result

[image]

[image]

Comment: might be there is something wrong with a skip part, can you debug by console.log, what you are getting in the skip variable, and query?

Comment: @turivishal I'm getting data from the back-end properly. skip is the useState hook with default set to 0. when I'm scrolling get another 4 set of data and then 3 and so on.

Comment: I can help you with the backend part or Mongodb query, if it is working then there might be some issue in frontend logic, someone will help you.

Comment: @turivishal can you check the query? do i need to add more fields to sort?

Comment: Well, it is up to your requirement, by which fields/order you want to sort the records and represent in front-end.

Comment: @turivishal i want to get latest records at the top so that's why I added _id for the sort. my issue now is getting the same record multiple times. lets say first fetch I get A, B, C, D and next I get C, E, D, F etc...  Is it because shuffling the records i guess.

Comment: in a previous comment, you said *"I'm getting data from the back-end properly"*, so i said if it not correct then you have to check skip part. no issue in sort